# Open gedit by using C(Linux)

Tags: c, linux, gedit

I'd like to write a program to open `gedit` by using C ? When i run `.c` file in `terminal`, `gedit` will automatically open.

```
int loop_forever = 1;

void on_sigint(){
printf("You pressed CTRL-C\n");
loop_forever = 0;
}

int main()
{
 loop_forever = 1;
 printf("Testing\n");
 system(gedit); /*Error*/
 while(loop_forever){
    signal(SIGINT,on_sigint);
  }
}
```

I'm on Linux.

Comment: `system(gedit)`?

Comment: `system("gedit")` is what I meant of course.

Comment: @kaylum It worked

Comment: There's more wrong with that code than what's bothering you right now.  `loop_forever` needs to be `volatile` if you're accessing it within your signal handler, and you need to check the return value from `system()`.